# ERROR: constraint for relation already exists with hibernate 4.3.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have this error when running the dll generated the hibernate

```
Failed to execute:   alter table sezioniastratte add constraint FK_5nekcygup70my0ixo073o215d foreign key (padre_id) references sezioni
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: constraint "fk_5nekcygup70my0ixo073o215d" for relation "sezioniastratte" already exists
```

I'm mapping a complex structure, in particular, a structure with the composite pattern, this is the class diagram:

[image: Class diagram]

This is my code of the classes

```
package it.unibas.webanalytics.modello;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

/**
 *
 * @author Vincenzo Palazzo
 */
@Entity(name = "sezioniastratte")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class AbstractSezione implements ISezione {

    private Long id;
    protected String identificativo;
    private AbstractSezione root;
    private AbstractSezione padre;

    public AbstractSezione(String identificativo) {
        this.identificativo = identificativo;
    }

    public AbstractSezione() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 150)
    public String getIdentificativo() {
        return identificativo;
    }

    public void setIdentificativo(String identificativo) {
        this.identificativo = identificativo;
    }

    @OneToOne
    public AbstractSezione getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(AbstractSezione root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public AbstractSezione getPadre() {
        return padre;
    }

    public void setPadre(AbstractSezione padre) {
        this.padre = padre;
    }


}
```

```
package it.unibas.webanalytics.modello;

import it.unibas.webanalytics.modello.visite.IVisitor;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

/**
 *
 * @author Vincenzo Palazzo
 */
@Entity(name = "pagine")
public class Pagina extends AbstractSezione{

    @Deprecated
    private String uuid;
    private List<Visualizzazione> visualizzazioni = new ArrayList<>();

    public Pagina(String identificativo) {
        super(identificativo);
        uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public Pagina() {
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pagina", orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<Visualizzazione> getVisualizzazioni() {
        return visualizzazioni;
    }

    public void addVisualizzazione(Visualizzazione visualizzazione){
        visualizzazioni.add(visualizzazione);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPage(){
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(IVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitaPagina(this);
    }

    @Transient
    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public void setVisualizzazioni(List<Visualizzazione> visualizzazioni) {
        this.visualizzazioni = visualizzazioni;
    }


    public int dimensione(){
        return this.visualizzazioni.size();
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(super.identificativo);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.uuid);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Pagina other = (Pagina) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(super.identificativo, other.identificativo)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.uuid, other.uuid)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }    
}
```

```
package it.unibas.webanalytics.modello;

import it.unibas.webanalytics.modello.visite.IVisitor;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

/**
 *
 * @author Vincenzo Palazzo
 */
@Entity(name = "sezioni")
public class Sezione extends AbstractSezione {

    private List<AbstractSezione> sezioniList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Sezione() {
    }

    public Sezione(String identificativo) {
        super(identificativo);
    }

    public void addSezione(AbstractSezione sezione) {
        sezioniList.add(sezione);
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "padre")
    public List<AbstractSezione> getSezioniList() {
        return sezioniList;
    }

    public void setSezioniList(List<AbstractSezione> sezioniList) {
        this.sezioniList = sezioniList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPage() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(IVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitaSezione(this);
    }

}
```

```
package it.unibas.webanalytics.modello;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

/**
 *
 * @author Vincenzo Palazzo
 */
@Entity(name = "portali")
public class PortaleWeb {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 50)
    private String nomeDominio;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 50)
    private String indirizzoIp;
    @Column(length = 20)
    private String indestatario;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "root")
    private AbstractSezione sezione;

    public PortaleWeb() {
    }

    public PortaleWeb(String nomeDominio, String indirizzoIp, String indestatario, AbstractSezione sezione) {
        this.nomeDominio = nomeDominio;
        this.indirizzoIp = indirizzoIp;
        this.indestatario = indestatario;
        this.sezione = sezione;
    }

    public String getNomeDominio() {
        return nomeDominio;
    }

    public String getIndirizzoIp() {
        return indirizzoIp;
    }

    public String getIndestatario() {
        return indestatario;
    }

    public ISezione getSezione() {
        return sezione;
    }

    public void setNomeDominio(String nomeDominio) {
        this.nomeDominio = nomeDominio;
    }

    public void setIndirizzoIp(String indirizzoIp) {
        this.indirizzoIp = indirizzoIp;
    }

    public void setIndestatario(String indestatario) {
        this.indestatario = indestatario;
    }

    public void setSezione(AbstractSezione sezione) {
        this.sezione = sezione;
    }

}
```

```
package it.unibas.webanalytics.modello;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

/**
 *
 * @author Vincenzo Palazzo
 */
@Entity(name = "visualizzazioni")
public class Visualizzazione {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String nazioneDiProvenienza;
    @Column(length = 250)
    private String urlProvenienza;
    @Column(length = 250)
    private String urlDestinazione;
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String browser;
    private int daQuanto;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Pagina pagina;

    public Visualizzazione() {
    }

    public Visualizzazione(String nazioneDiProvenienza, String urlProvenienza, String urlDestinazione, String browser, int daQuanto) {
        this.nazioneDiProvenienza = nazioneDiProvenienza;
        this.urlProvenienza = urlProvenienza;
        this.urlDestinazione = urlDestinazione;
        this.browser = browser;
        this.daQuanto = daQuanto;
    }

    public String getNazioneDiProvenienza() {
        return nazioneDiProvenienza;
    }

    public String getUrlProvenienza() {
        return urlProvenienza;
    }

    public String getUrlDestinazione() {
        return urlDestinazione;
    }

    public String getBrowser() {
        return browser;
    }

    public int getDaQuanto() {
        return daQuanto;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Pagina getPagina() {
        return pagina;
    }

    public void setPagina(Pagina pagina) {
        this.pagina = pagina;
    }

    public void setNazioneDiProvenienza(String nazioneDiProvenienza) {
        this.nazioneDiProvenienza = nazioneDiProvenienza;
    }

    public void setUrlProvenienza(String urlProvenienza) {
        this.urlProvenienza = urlProvenienza;
    }

    public void setUrlDestinazione(String urlDestinazione) {
        this.urlDestinazione = urlDestinazione;
    }

    public void setBrowser(String browser) {
        this.browser = browser;
    }

    public void setDaQuanto(int daQuanto) {
        this.daQuanto = daQuanto;
    }

}
```

```
This is the DLL generate by hibernate


    create table pagine (
        page boolean not null,
        id int8 not null,
        primary key (id)
    );

    create table portali (
        id int8 not null,
        indestatario varchar(20),
        indirizzoIp varchar(50) not null,
        nomeDominio varchar(50) not null,
        primary key (id)
    );

    create table sezioni (
        page boolean not null,
        id int8 not null,
        primary key (id)
    );

    create table sezioniastratte (
        id int8 not null,
        identificativo varchar(150) not null,
        padre_id int8,
        root_id int8,
        primary key (id)
    );

    create table utente (
        id int8 not null,
        attivo boolean not null,
        lastLogin timestamp,
        nome varchar(255),
        nomeUtente varchar(255),
        password varchar(255),
        ruolo varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    );

    create table visualizzazioni (
        id int8 not null,
        browser varchar(50),
        daQuanto int4 not null,
        nazioneDiProvenienza varchar(50),
        urlDestinazione varchar(250),
        urlProvenienza varchar(250),
        pagina_id int8,
        primary key (id)
    );

    alter table portali 
        add constraint UK_7h0fmoqq22xrlcvgnrybiafgb unique (indirizzoIp);

    alter table portali 
        add constraint UK_jywg6ldg7jvgfjgaw9u81bfp8 unique (nomeDominio);

    alter table sezioniastratte 
        add constraint UK_b0jnspivif39dgey09negpjjp unique (identificativo);

    alter table utente 
        add constraint UK_7hipuu05v6vcqr7wbl8q7p4t2 unique (nomeUtente);

    alter table pagine 
        add constraint FK_tijtvrfbi6n06ocq6fpffgdy9 
        foreign key (id) 
        references sezioniastratte;

    alter table sezioni 
        add constraint FK_t88ok4wbwbhdtipul9l11xued 
        foreign key (id) 
        references sezioniastratte;

    alter table sezioniastratte 
        add constraint FK_5nekcygup70my0ixo073o215d 
        foreign key (padre_id) 
        references sezioniastratte;

    alter table sezioniastratte 
        add constraint FK_d0cntmtmcp2wvl6hqr8ddgg8w 
        foreign key (root_id) 
        references sezioniastratte;

    alter table sezioniastratte 
        add constraint FK_5nekcygup70my0ixo073o215d 
        foreign key (padre_id) 
        references sezioni;

    alter table visualizzazioni 
        add constraint FK_dblrq69ykw1wch2pn845p4xf7 
        foreign key (pagina_id) 
        references pagine;

    create table hibernate_sequences (
         sequence_name varchar(255),
         sequence_next_hi_value int4 
    );
```

**[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534063/error-constraint-for-relation-already-exists-with-hibernate-4-3-1?noredirect=1#comment99661443_56534063)**

Sorry for the class diagram wrong but not have another example also sorry for my terrible English but I'm learning

Comment: Do the tables already exists or are they completely new created?

Comment: I recreated all, drop-db, create-db and create-table

Comment: and create table with Hibernate?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have a task ant that gives a dll file and do inserts into db, but I have this error

Comment: So you first execute the ddl file and then let hibernate create the tables again?

Comment: No @SimonMartinelli with schema export hibernate generated the dll and I with hibernate I do insert the table generated by hibernate into db

Comment: The error says that constraint fk_5nekcygup70my0ixo073o215d already exisits so it is already created. Are you really sure that the database is empty?

Comment: Oh yes @SimonMartinelli I deleted the db and recreated it, if I remove this into dll `alter table sezioniastratte 
        add constraint FK_5nekcygup70my0ixo073o215d 
        foreign key (padre_id) 
        references sezioni;` the code work on the db but I did had the effect  indesiderate form the "Sezioni have a list the AbstractSezioni" I have updated the uml now the association from the class are well

Comment: I think i've found the issue but I don't understand your model Why does the abstract class have the padre? Only in case of Sezione you have this relationship?

Comment: Thanks for your help @SimonMartinelli, into abstract class exist two proprieties `private AbstractSezione root;
private AbstractSezione padre;` I use they for the mapping ManyToOne, into class with OneToMeny(mappedBy = "root"). This is wrong?

Comment: But why? Pagina does not have this?

Comment: No pagina does not have the padre propriety into UML but into the schema, the padre will is null, right?

Comment: Yes but you have a list of children in the Sezione and the padre in the Abstract class. That causes the problem

Comment: The problem is caused to List<AbstractSezione> sezioniList into Sezione? this list must be AbstractList because of a Sezione could be is a Pagina

Comment: No the list must be in the AbstractSezione or the padre must be in the Sezione

Comment: Oh yesss, now works all well, thanks so much @SimonMartinelli, Unfortunately, I only need two points of reputation to vote for your correct answer, as soon as I get them I will vote for your correct answer

Comment: Ok. I added my comment as the answer. And really appreciate it when you will accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed with the realtionships on the hierarchy levels.

Either the list must be in the `AbstractSezione` or the padre must be in the `Sezione`.